# How to get an ordered list of categories by names from IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord, model

I loaded data from database, like:

```
@cars = Car.where(...).order('created_at DESC').group_by { |r| r.voted.to_date }
```

Then, in a view, I do:

```
- @cars.each do |key, arr|
  - categories = arr.uniq{|x| x.category_id} # so here I should get list of objects with uniuque category ID
  ...
  - arr.each do |car|
    ... print information about car ...
```

How can I order this list of `categories` by their name? In the `car` model, there's the attribute `category_id`.

Comment: Is there any relationship between Car and Category?

Comment: Hi @Masud, yes - car belongs_to category (but has always one) and categories has many cars.

Answer (score 0):

In order use `category.name ASC`. Try,

```
@cars = Car.includes(:category).where(...).order('category.name ASC')
```

Answer (score 0):

"How can I order this list of categories by their name?" This brings to mind to use scopes.

Here's the setup: In category.rb

```
  scope :by_name, -> { order(name: :asc) }
```

Now you have a reference handle to grab category.name sorted ascending.

So, in your view, you could do something like this for each |car|

```
<% if car.categories.by_name.any? %>
  <%= render category_name_partial", collection:...%>
     etc.
```

I used '.any?' only to illustrate that you have a sorted collection as a result of this action, your listed sorted by name based on scope defined by "by_name".